# Agda Programming- Proving Insertionsort makes 3 or less comparisons on a list of size 3

Tags: functional-programming, insertion-sort, agda

Good Evening Fellows,

I am attempting to prove that insertionsort will perform <= 3 comparisons in a list of size 3 while sorting.  Last part of my project and cannot make any headway on it.  After spending fair amount of time pursuing an incorrect approach, my instructor informed me it may be accomplished by writing a helper function to assist.  I unfortunately have not come up with any piece of code to help.  If anyone can offer advice or assistance, any and all are appreciated.  Code follows.  Thanks!

```
insert : ℕ →  ℕ →  ℕ × ℕ 
insert x (h :: t) = if h < x then (x :: h :: t , 1) else let r = insert 
                                       x t  in h :: (fst r) , 1 + snd r
insert x [] = x :: [] , 0

insertionsort :  ℕ →  ℕ × ℕ 
insertionsort [] = [] , 0
insertionsort (h :: t) with insertionsort t
insertionsort (h :: t) | t' , c1 with insert h t' 
insertionsort (h :: t) | t' , c1 | r , c2 = r , c1 + c2

exampleThm : ∀(x y z c : ℕ)(r :  ℕ) → insertionsort (x :: y :: z :: [])
                                                    ≡ r , c → c ≤ 3 ≡ tt 
exampleThm x y z = ?`
```

Comment: You need to reflect type-level pattern matching at the value level. So your proof will contain these parts: `with insertionsort (y :: z :: [])`, `with insert x (y :: z :: [])`, `with insertionsort (z :: [])` and `with insert x (z :: [])`. You can find some explanations in the [Dependently Typed Programming in Agda](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~ulfn/papers/afp08/tutorial.pdf) tutorial in the 2.6 section.

Answer (score 2):

All the comparisons to be done in the course of `insertionsort` are actually done in the course of subordinate calls to `insert`. It may help to establish a useful fact about the comparison cost of `insert`. If you can bound the cost of each call to `insert`, you should be able to combine those bounded partial costs together to make a bounded total cost. In case your instructor is concerned that I am helping too much, let me summarize by saying that all I am saying is that the structure of the proof has to follow the structure of the program.

Comment: Thank you for assisting, however this little proof has made a fool of me.  I'm wasting time trying to figure this out, and not studying for other finals.  Appreciate your attempting to explain, just not coming together for me.

Answer (score 1):

A general pattern when constructing proofs is to generalize them to make them easier. In this case I believe it is more clear to solve the generalized bound for the number of comparisons that insertion sort will do and then instantiate that to your particular input.

The structure of your proof will follow the structure of your program.

First we'll need to characterize the behavior of insert, since insertion sort is implemented in terms of it.

```
insert-bound : ∀ x ys → proj₂ (insert x ys) ≤ length ys
```

Then we'll use that to characterize the behavior of insertion sort

```
bound         : ℕ → ℕ
bound 0       = 0
bound (suc n) = bound n + n

insertionsort-bound : ∀ xs → proj₂ (insertionsort xs) ≤ bound (length xs)
```

Using the general solution we can solve the specific case of a three element list

```
exampleThm : ∀ x y z c r → insertionsort (x ∷ y ∷ z ∷ []) ≡ (r , c) → c ≤ 3
exampleThm x y z ._ ._ refl = insertionsort-bound (x ∷ y ∷ z ∷ [])
```

Here's an implementation against the Agda standard library of your problem:

http://www.galois.com/~emertens/insertionsort-agda/Insertionsort.html